# Object Method Reference Variable is not the Object method

Tags: python, function, class

After initializing an object attribute to point to an object method, the variable will not be evaluated as being the same (using 'is') as the object method. It will still be evaluated as having equality (==) with the method.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.command = self.do_something

    def do_stuff(self):
        print('c1:', id(self.command))
        print('c2:', id(self.do_something))
        if self.command is self.do_something:
            return 'Commands match (is)'
        elif self.command == self.do_something:
            return 'Commands match (==)'
        return 'Commands do not match at all'
    def do_something(self):
        pass


some_object = SomeClass()
print(some_object.do_stuff())
print()

def some_func():
    pass
command = some_func
print('c1:', id(some_func))
print('c2:', id(command))
if some_func is command:
    print('Commands match (is)')
else:
    'Commands do not match at all'
```

I was expecting the ids of self.command and self.do_something to be the same just like some_func and command ids are the same.

Comment: They are not. `self.do_something` returns a *new bound method object* every time you access it

Comment: When I add the following check they seem to have equality:

        ```elif self.command == self.do_something:```

Comment: You should read [how instance methods work](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) in the [Desciptor HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you access a method via an *instance*, you get back a new instance of `method` that wraps both the instance and the underlying function. Two `method` instances compare as equal if they wrap the same instance and the same function. (This is not documented anywhere as far as I know—it's not mentioned in the documentation for instance method objects—but can be seen in the [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/methodobject.c#L306).)

So even though `self.command` (a previously created bound method) and `self.do_something` are distinct instances of `method`, they both wrap the same instance (`self`) of `SomeClass` and the same function (`SomeClass.do_something`).

Details on how `function` values produce `method` instances can be found in  the [Descriptor HowTo guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

(Instance method objects are documented in [Section 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) of the language documentation.)